# How to compare two column from different table and differentiate in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am comparing two tables with same column no but approach of difference.

For Eg.

table1

```
id  roll    no 
1   123456  same-ignore
2   123457  different
3   123458  same-ignore
4   123879  different
5   123888  same-ignore
```

table2

```
id  roll    no 
1   123456  same-ignore
2   123467  different
3   123458  same-ignore
4   123852  different
5   123888  same-ignore
```

I followed below examples as well but result not achieved.

[SQL how to compare two columns from two different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886856/sql-how-to-compare-two-columns-from-two-different-tables)
[comparing columns in two different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627524/comparing-columns-in-two-different-tables)
[Comparing two columns in two different tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26336312/comparing-two-columns-in-two-different-tables)
[Compare a column in two different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705244/compare-a-column-in-two-different-tables)

I got first output with this query.

```
select distinct roll no from table2 where rollno not in (select roll no from table1)
```

I can't do the same for second output, meaning I can't differentiate table1 with table2 (it returns null rows)

How can I achieve?

output 1: (not in table1)

```
123467
123852
```

output 2:(not in table2)

```
123457
123879
```

Comment: So you want all rows in table 1 that are not in table 2 and vice versa? O you want the rows where the corresponding rolls are not the same (first-first, second-second...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use left and right join
for output 1

```
select t2.roll from table1 t1 
  right
 join table2 t2 on t1.roll=t2.roll
where t1.roll is null
```

for output 2

```
select t1.roll from table1 t1 
  left
 join table2 t2 on t1.roll=t2.roll
where t2.roll is null
```

Comment: @RexJones in which query 1st or 2nd?

Comment: @RexJones sorry from was missing now you can check

Comment: Query 2 returns result which I already have. But Query 1 returns null, meaning no rows for output1.

Comment: @RexJones do u have fiddle to show me how it thrown null

Comment: It worked, I had to look over 8k records and it seemed that it had garbage values.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have the rolls from `table1` that are not in `table2` you could go with this

```
SELECT roll FROM table1
WHERE roll NOT IN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT roll FROM table2
);

UNION

SELECT roll FROM table2
WHERE roll NOT IN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT roll FROM table1
);
```

If, instead, you're looking for the non-matching roll-pairs between the rows (first with first, second with second, ...) you can use a simple `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.roll 
FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id == t2.id
WHERE t1.roll <> t2.roll
```

Comment: Second query did not run.

Comment: Error no 1064, you have an error in your sql syntax, I am using mysql workbench.

Comment: Just to check, try replacing `<>` with `!=`